# OpenAM Configuration

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, openam, opensso, opendj

I have been trying to configure OpenAM in my laptop to no success. 
Here's what I have done.

1. Deployed the war file on tomcat server(successfully running at localhost)
2. Installed OpenDJ successfully.( Server up and running)
3. Followed the tutorial give on ForgeRock but I am stuck up here:
   It is giving two kinds of errors, either says server cannot be contacted or says that cannot recognize root suffix.

[Here is what I am getting!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjHb6.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During initial configuration you should not use external data store, just use embedded one and configure external one later on.

Can not be contacted seems more like a resolver issue ...

Another note as this is the data store you may not use suffix 'dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=wipro' .... you are not Forgerock ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Well it could be many things:

- Incorrect host provided
- Incorrect port provided
- Firewall issues
- other networking issues

You should check whether you can access the directory from the box (where the container actually runs):

```
telnet L-0156009091.wipro.com 50389
```